# Does Hudson have a build hung notifier?

Tags: hudson, jenkins, hudson-plugins

When using Bamboo there is a build notifier (mostly a timer) that sends an e-mail notification when your build has been running unusually long.  I've hunted around and could not find a similar feature for Hudson.  Does Hudson have a build hung notifier or suitable plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build time-out plugin helps you to set a time-out value and hudson terminates the build if time-out is exceeded. Though not exactly what you are looking for, hope this solves your problem to some extent.

[Hudson Bulit Timeout Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Build-timeout+Plugin)